# I need to append result of Aggregation in mongoDb with average and sum of different columns

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have an aggegation for mongo Query, which gives me result like this

```
[
{
    tokens : 129,
    avgwaitingTime : 5,
    service: 'xx'
},
{
    tokens : 9,
    avgwaitingTime : 1,
    service: "yy"
}
]
```

What i need to do is to append that result by add a row containing sum of tokens, average of all avgwaitingTime using aggregation, like this.

```
[
    {
        tokens : 129,
        avgwaitingTime : 5,
        service: 'xx'
    },
    {
        tokens : 9,
        avgwaitingTime : 1,
        service: "yy"
    },
    {
        tokens : 138, // sum of all tokens
        avgwaitingTime : 3 // avg of avgwaitingTime (6+1)/2
        service : ''
    }
]
```

Last part in my aggregation is $project

```
[
   ..//////
   ..//////
   $project:{
      tokens: '$tokens',
      service: '$service',
      avgwaitingTime: '$avgwaitingTime'
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Basically you want two([**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) + [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)) result with the same pipline here. So, you need to further divide your `pipeline` into two parts and that is what [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) provides.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "lastPart": [
      { "$project": {
        "tokens": "$tokens",
        "service": "$service",
        "avgwaitingTime": "$avgwaitingTime"
      }}
    ],
    "total": [
      { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "tokens": { "$sum": "$tokens" },
        "avgwaitingTime": { "$sum": "$avgwaitingTime" }
      }}
    ]
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "data": {
      "$concatArrays": ["$total", "$lastPart"]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LeB7hvaOa8C)